# Wordpress navigation using slug instead of page title?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress, just been setting it all up with my own theme and it's looking great, however the navigation displays the page title as links whereas I'd prefer it to show the slug instead. Do you know how I could do this?

It's the wp_nav_menu which displays the nav li's. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What is the `wp_nav_menu` code you are using? Is this menu being set in the section `Dashboard` **- - >** `Appearance` **- - >** `Menus`?

Answer (score 0):

Your going to want to check your permalink settings to make sure everything is set up there. The "Post Name" option would probably be most helpful for you. Just click on Settings -> Permalinks and select the "Post Name" radio button.

More info here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Choosing_your_permalink_structure